# Смена фрагментов через меню android

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно менять фрагменты через меню в android.
У меня вылезает ошибка в строчке:

```
fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

И вот весь код из activity:
Fragment1 frag1;
Fragment2 frag2;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    frag1 = new Fragment1();
    frag2 = new Fragment2();
    
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch(id){
        case R.id.action_settings :
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   "Настройки", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    fTrans.remove(frag1);
                    break;
            return true;
        case R.id.look_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Поиск", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    fTrans.remove(frag2);
                    break;
            return true;
        case R.id.end_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Выход", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
    }
    //headerView.setText(item.getTitle());
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Ошибка:
AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Comment: Покажите лог ошибки или сообщение компилятора/линтера. Также не видно, чтобы вы делали `commit` транзакции

Comment: @ЮрийСПб отредактировал вопрос и добавил ошибку

Comment: покажите разметку вашей активности, вот есть ее упоминание - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089718/error-error-parsing-xml-not-well-formed-invalid-token